# Как работает Arrays.toList (E ... a)?

Tags: java, list, коллекции

Есть код:

```
List<Integer> c1 = new ArrayList<>(
             Arrays.asList(new Integer(1394), new Integer(52837))
             ); 
List<Integer> c2 = Arrays.asList(new Integer[c1.size()]);
```

Как мы вообще присваиваем `c2` значение? На что мы ссылаемся, если `Array.asList(T... a)` возвращает `<T> List <T>`?
Я даже не понимаю, что это за странный тип возвращаемого значения.
Мораль в том, что возвращается некоторый `List`, но `List` — это интерфейс. Значит, мы получим ссылку на объект, для которого определено действие `.add(E o);` Но почему-то вызов `c2.add` в данном случае вызывает ошибку.
Почему так?

Comment: По поводу `<T>` стоит прочитать что такое generics. По поводу ошибки при вызове `c2.add` - потому что метод `Arrays.asList` возвращает список (реализацию `List`), который является неизменяемым. Однако так как он реализует интерфейс `List`, то метод `add` в нём есть. Несколько криво, но уж как придумали.

Comment: Кажется, Вас я понял. Я так и предполагал, что метод `.add(...)` есть, но он "псевдоподобный"... Но точно ли это так?

Comment: Точно. Во-первых, в документации к методу `Arrays.asList` говорится, что возвращается список фиксированного размера. Во-вторых, можно посмотреть исходный код. В этом самом методе возвращается `ArrayList` (не обычный `ArrayList`, а внутренний `ArrayList` из класса `Arrays`), в котором метод `add` не переопределён и действует ровно так же, как в родительском классе `AbstractList`, а именно пробрасывает `UnsupportedOperationException`.

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Как же здорово по настоящему познавать то, чем занимаешься !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Arrays.asList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29) - возвращает список **фиксированного** размера. Поэтому нельзя ни добавлять, ни удалять. Чтобы как-то манипулировать элементами, придется оборачивать в новый список без фиксированного размера:

```
// List<Integer> c2 = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(new Integer[c1.size()]));
List<Integer> c2 = new LinkedList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(new Integer[c1.size()]));
```

---

Если углубиться:

Во внутренностях метод `Arrays.asList` возвращает следующее:

```
return new ArrayList<>(a);
```

**но(!!!)**  возвращает он `ArrayList` не тот, который находится в пакете`java.util.ArrayList` а тот, который  определен как внутренний класс внутри самого `java.util.Arrays;`. Выглядит он так:

```
private static class ArrayList<E> extends AbstractList<E> implements RandomAccess, java.io.Serializable  {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2764017481108945198L;
    private final E[] a;
    //.... и т.д. реализация
}
```

Как видим, эта внутренняя реализация наследуется от `AbstractList`, в котором по дефолту определены некоторые методы в таком виде

```
public boolean add(E e) {
    add(size(), e);
    return true;
}

public void add(int index, E element) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}

public E remove(int index) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}
```

Вот и получается, что вроде как вернули `ArrayList`, но на самом деле не тот лист, который ожидали (java.util.ArrayList), а эмуляцию.

---

О том, что такое `<T>` и `<T> List <T>` стоит прочитать материалы на тему *generics* или *обобщений*. Тема очень широкая.

Comment: Начну с конца. О generics в книге, по которой я сейчас занимаюсь, говорится позже, обязательно изучу эту тему! Так понимаю, что это подобие шаблонов в c++
Алексей, объясните пожалуйста, Как понять фиксированного размера? У нас же для объектов, выражающих интерфейс `List`, ясно, что реализован метод `.add(...)`?  Как в данном случае это объясняется? Он реализован, но генерирует ошибку? Я правда не очень понимаю... 
`List<Integer> c2` (объявили ссылку на объект класса Список). 
`= Arrays.asList (...)` сослали его на **созданный** в методе `asList()` список. Так? Как тогда реализован там .add?

Comment: @Direct дописал в ответ, а то в комментарии слишком в одну строку всё пошло

Comment: Алексей, огромное Вам спасибо!!!

Answer (score 2):

Метод `Arrays.asList` возвращает список фиксированного размера. А именно объект типа `java.util.Arrays.ArrayList`. Не стоит путать его с обычным, изменяемого размера списком `java.util.ArrayList`.

Данный класс (`Arrays.ArrayList`) служит "мостом" между взаимодействием с элементами как с массивом и как со списком.

Неизменяемость размера списка достигается пробрасыванием `UnsupportedOperationException` при попытке добавить или удалить элемент в список.

Безусловно, это не идеальное решение, особенно если такой список будет передан в метод, который и знать не знает, что это "особенный" список, у которого нельзя вызывать методы `add` и `remove`, и просто работает с ним через контракт интерфейса `List`.
Но зато оно позволяет просто и эффективно передать массив в метод, который принимает на вход список/коллекцию и не изменяет размер переданного списка (как правило, используя список только для чтения).

Фиксированный размер списка и прямая связь с исходным массивом позволяют сэкономить память и время, так как нет необходимости создавать дополнительный массив и копировать в него элементы из исходного массива.
В прямой связи с исходным массивом можно убедиться на следующем примере:

```
Integer[] array = { 1, 2, 3 };
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(array);
list.set(0, 10);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
```

> [10, 2, 3]

---

`<T>` - это generics-тип. Соответственно, если в качестве значений в метод `Arrays.asList` вы передаёте `Integer`, то и результирующий список будет иметь тип `Integer` (`List<Integer>`).

Comment: Ещё раз пишу свои благодарности здесь! Большое человеческое спасибо! Как разобрался, жить проще стало :)

Comment: @Direct на здоровье .Решение, принятое в `Arrays.asList`, безусловно, неочевидное, поэтому приходится с ним разбираться отдельно.